# Custom coordinates on Follow me Mission DJI Mobile SDK for android

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Is it possible to feed DJI Mobile API's `Follow Me Mission` custom coordinates? I am developing on the'Phantom 3 Advanced'. For example:

```
 Double Lat = 33.8943;
 Double Lon = 32.0993;

 DJIFollowMe(Lat, Lon){
   // Execute the follow me mission
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following is an example:

```
        DJIFollowMeMission.updateFollowMeCoordinate(latitude, longitude, new DJICommonCallbacks.DJICompletionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does this update the coordinate constantly? I mean if the drone is on the air does will still receiving coordinates in case when the device that will follow change its coordinates?

Comment: This is a method your app should call; you should call the method to send updated coordinates as quickly as you want the UAV to move.

Comment: for some reason I can't init the FollowMe mission on the latest version of DJI.. any idea?

Comment: 4.0 or 3.5?  The SDK update to 4.0 has changed significantly.

Comment: I am using the latest 4.0