# Android DJI SDK - Dynamic GoToAction with MissionControl

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I want to give Phantom 4 a Go to Point Mission with MissionControl.
I added new element - GoToAction with point.
There is a way to change dynamically the point in the element So that the Drone does not stop and will go to the new point,  but will continue on a flowing flight to the new point?

Thank You!

Comment: I don't see any questions or problems stated in your *question*

Comment: I want my Drone follow a moving target that have 2D location. So I need to give the Drone a dynamic point to go (The location of the target. Im not using ActiveTrack, I want it to go GPS location)

Comment: and the problem is... continue. Why you can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think You can not. There must be a new Mission//Waypoint for each position, so the only way to do it is: create a new Mission with just one Waypoint, upload it and start the Mission, each time you get a new GPS location from the moving object.

But You could use the DJIFollowMeMissionOperator, there You could set a target-Position

Edit: here is my Example, I tested a few times, important is to update the targetPosition before the Mission will timeout. so for Example use a timer or the FlightcontrollerStateCallback to update the followMeTargetPosition:

in my class MissionControlWrapper:

To start the mission:

```
public void startSimpleFollowMe(){
    if(fmmo == null){
        fmmo = getFollowMeMissionOperator();
    }
    final FollowMeMissionOperator followMeMissionOperator  = fmmo;
    if (followMeMissionOperator.getCurrentState().equals(FollowMeMissionState.READY_TO_EXECUTE)){
        fmm = FollowMeMission.getInstance().initUserData(targetLocation.getLatitude() , targetLocation.getLongitude(),0);
        followMeMissionOperator.startMission(fmm, new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
                if(djiError != null){
                    setLastState(djiError.getDescription());
                } else {
                    setLastState("Mission Start: Successfully");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To Update the target:

```
public void updateSimpleFollowMe(){
    if(fmmo == null){
        fmmo = getFollowMeMissionOperator();
    }
    final FollowMeMissionOperator followMeMissionOperator  = fmmo;
    if(followMeMissionOperator.getCurrentState().equals(FollowMeMissionState.EXECUTING)) {
        followMeMissionOperator.updateFollowingTarget(new LocationCoordinate2D(targetLocation.getLatitude(),
                        targetLocation.getLongitude()),
                new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DJIError error) {
                        if (error != null) {
                            setLastState(followMeMissionOperator.getCurrentState().getName().toString() + " " + error.getDescription());
                        } else {
                            setLastState("Mission Update Successfully");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I update

> targetLocation

from outside the class and then call

> startSimpleFollowMe()

and update TargetPosition with

> updateSimpleFollowMe()

After starting the mission: wait for "Mission Start: Successfully".

then update the targetLocation in an interval (seems that it works from once a second to every 3 seconds)

I use FollowMe instead of a WaypointMission to change the targetLocation whenever I want, without starting a new mission.
If the actual target is more than 2 Meters away, I update the target in steps of one meter, cause if the distance between drone and targetPosition is to high, you will get errors.

I have to try a few more things but this seems to be a solution :)

Comment: Thank!  FollowMeMissionOperator seems like a good solution. have you some examples for Android how to do that?

Comment: At first You need the DJIMissionControl, then the FollowMeMissionOperator. With it, You are able to set new TargetLocation and start//Stop the mission. For an example look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48549860/9360274

Comment: Nice! Thank u very much. There is a way to set the flights speed in the FollowMe mission?

Comment: It seams not, in other Missions like TapFlyMission You are able to set Speed, but FollowMeMission seems not to support changing speed. and I think that's OK, cause of the Speed of the Copter depends on the speed of the moving object.

Comment: I used the example you sent to me. I set the Atlitude to 10 Meters and than try again with 20 Meters in the initUserData function, but it catch a DJIError - "the altitude is too low". why it tell the height is to low? 20 Meters is not enough? thank you!

Comment: the SKD reference: https://developer.dji.com/iframe/mobile-sdk-doc/android/reference/dji/sdk/MissionManager/DJIFollowMeMission.html says: altitude: user's initial altitude (above sea level) so i think You were on a place on earth where 20 meters is below the surface :)  but You can use zero if You don't want to use altitude folow....

Comment: Actually I am checking this mission at the ocean beach :)    But its still show me the -" the altitude is too low" error even after I try to set it to 0 and  40 meters... The Phantom rotate to the target location but not move at all... there is another solution?

Comment: Hey, please check again my answer, I inserted some code for You,:)

Comment: So the problem was that my GPS was not callibrate. After callibration it say that the mission started succesfully. the drone rotate to the target direction and it locked so I cant control it with the remote. But it dont fly to the location I set. Also the UpdateLoaction give error - Execution could not be executed, or - Execution of this process has timed out. Any Idea?

Comment: Yes, but i still need some time, I think the FollowMeMission is more complex then i thought. Sometimes i runn into the same issue.

Comment: Hey There, it seems that there are several problems with the followMeMission, I tested a lot the last days, in rl and in simulator, sometimes it works with updating the targetLocation every 1.5second, but sometimes there is still a Timeout error. Actually I use a workaround with a Waypoint mission, but its not as dynamic as the FollowMeMission, cause it needs some time to init and upload the mission, and there should be a little delay between uploading and starting the mission. But I still work on the FollowMeMission!