# GPS Signal of the aircraft is weak-Using simulator and FollowMeMissionOperator

Tags: dji-sdk

(Mobile SDK) I get 'Error- the GPS Signal of the aircraft is weak(216)' when I try to start a FollowMe mission while using the simulator i.e. on the line
FollowMeMissionOp.startMission(followMeInitSettings, new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback()...
where
FollowMeMissionOp = DJISDKManager.getInstance().getMissionControl().getFollowMeMissionOperator();

I'm using the code at
[Custom Follow Me Mission DJI Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404526/custom-follow-me-mission-dji-android-sdk?rq=1)
as my template, but the bulk of the code is irrelevant here as the error is thrown at the start.

I'm starting the simulator within the program...
mFlightController.getSimulator().start(InitializationData.createInstance(CenterScreen, 10, 10), new StartSimulatorCallback());

The simulator is working well for other types of missions- Waypoint, Timeline- with various actions, and indeed simple joystick control- there's quite a few things in the program at this stage that have tested it.

I cannot see anything different about using it for the FollowMeMissionOperator, so I'm inclined to think its a bug.

Can anyone throw any light on the issue?

(As a further footnote, it all works fine if I use the simulator in DJI Assistant instead of starting it with an SDK command)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you run the sim with only 10sats? The followmemission wont start with that few number of sats.

Btw, the builtin followme function sucks, at least on the mavics, you better of running your own with virtualsticks.

Comment: 100% correct. If I start the simulator with 15 satellites, it works fine with the FollowMe mission ie mFlightController.getSimulator().start(InitializationData.createInstance(CenterScreen, 10, 15), new StartSimulatorCallback());

Comment: Regarding your other point- I certainly have had issues with the FollowMe function, and I may indeed switch over to Virtual Sticks- if I post any of the issues, I'll leave a link here.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I done some followme with virtualsticks.
If you ran into other problems I can maybe help!
Here is an example of following a 4g tracker phone.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwAAdf6MBS0&ab_channel=MatsBohlinsson